# No attribution for tags in teams copied from public Q&A

Tags: feature-request, tags, stack-overflow-for-teams, tag-wiki, attribution

Stack Overflow for Teams will automatically use the tag excerpt and tag wiki from the public site if there isn't a team-specific tag excerpt/wiki created. For example, here's what [rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust) looks like after I tagged a question with it on a Team:

> [image: A tag wiki page for Rust on a team]

There is no attribution provided for the authors of the tag wiki content though. There should be a link somewhere to the revision history on public Q&A for attribution purposes.

Comment: This is on-topic for MSE - the tag wiki says that "general questions about the relationship between Teams and the public site" are ok.

Comment: Note: As of the move to a separate domain, I don't think Teams tags are connected to/drawn from SO public site tags anymore (nor is any tag info for public site tags used in Teams anymore, as far as I know). Should this be closed as no longer reproducible?